# Программное создание Layout'a

Tags: android, layout

В чем, при такой записи, указывается margin ? Просто чтобы он у меня был такой же, как при обычном создании в xml, мне приходится в коде указывать его в 2 раза больше. Вопрос, всегда ли так будет, или это только на некоторых устройствах ?

```
LinearLayout backgroundLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams backgroundLinearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    backgroundLinearLayoutParams.setMarginStart(24);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При программном задании все единицы указываются в пикселях. Для того, чтобы указывать в `dp`, необходимо их пересчитывать вручную - примерно так:

```
int dpValue = 15; // размер в dp
float d = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; //показатель плотности
int margin = (int)(dpValue * d); // размер в пикселях
```

Для пересчета в `sp`:

```
float spValue = 14.0;
float s = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
int margin = (int)(spValue * s) //размер в пикселях
```

Comment: А почему context ошибкой выделяется ?

Comment: Заменил на getApplicationContext, все работает